# diffent between "AND.. and ...and " and"and (and.. and)"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two statement sql for oracle 11gr2

sql1:

```
Select * from tableA inpt, tableB ptbs
where inpt.z='A'
AND (inpt.pid    = ptbs.pid
     AND  inpt.instcd = ptbs.instcd);
```

sql2:

```
Select * from tableA inpt, tableB ptbs
where inpt.z='A'
AND inpt.pid    = ptbs.pid
     AND  inpt.instcd = ptbs.instcd
```

Sql1 is faster than sql2?

The writing `... and ... and ... and ...` Slowly write `and (... and ... and (... and ... and ...))`?

Similar to "or"?

Comment: Why vote -2 for my question, while you can not answer

Comment: there should be no difference between your 2 statements. try running each multiple times first.. you might have a cache issue. otherwise try comparing explain plans.

Comment: They're logically the same. Check the explain plan and you should find there is no difference.

Comment: I run and found differnce between sql1 and sql2. I see Oracle have diffence process sql1 and sql2.

Comment: There is no difference between sql1 vs sql2,

Comment: The SQL parser knows [basic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) and does not in general change execution plan as a result of redundant bracketing. If you have an example where it does, please share it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference here.

```
 where inpt.z='A'
    AND (inpt.pid    = ptbs.pid
         AND  inpt.instcd = ptbs.instcd);
```

or

```
where inpt.z='A'
AND inpt.pid    = ptbs.pid
     AND  inpt.instcd = ptbs.instcd
```

or

```
where inpt.pid    = ptbs.pid
     AND  inpt.instcd = ptbs.instcd and inpt.z='A'
```

All is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It should probably just be written like:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA inpt
INNER JOIN tableB ptbs
ON inpt.pid = ptbs.pid
WHERE inpt.instcd = ptbs.instcd
AND inpt.z = 'A'
```

This might be worth a review: [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Comment: Not the answer I want. I know write as above